# Connecting to rabbitmq docker container from service in another container

Tags: python, docker, rabbitmq, nameko

I've done a lot of searching  but I cannot fix this issue.

I have a basic Rabbitmq container running via this command:

`docker run -d --hostname rabbitmqhost --name rabbitmq -p 15672:15672 -p 5672:5672 rabbitmq:3-management`

I am using `nameko` to create a microservice which connects to this container. Here's a basic microservice module `main.py`:

```
from nameko.rpc import rpc
class Service_Name(object):
    name = "service_name"

    @rpc
    def service_endpoint(self, arg=None):
        logging.info('service_one endpoint, arg = %s', arg)
```

This service runs and connects to the rabbitmq from my host machine with the command:

`nameko run main --broker amqp://guest:guest@localhost`

I wanted to put the service into a Docker container (called `service_one`) but when I do so and run the previous nameko command I get `socket.error: [Errno 111] ECONNREFUSED` no matter how I try and link the two containers.

What would be the correct method? The aim is to have each service in a container, all talking to each other through rabbit. Thanks.

Comment: "No matter how I try to link the two containers..."  What have you tried?

Comment: I tried link and network, turns out I was getting the ampq connection values slightly wrong for each method. (I was using localhost rather than AMQ_PORT_5672_TCP_ADDR etc).

Answer (score 31, accepted):

If you're running a service inside a container, then `amqp://guest:guest@localhost` won't do you any good; `localhost` refers to the network namespace of the container...so of course you get an `ECONNREFUSED`, because there's nothing listening there.

If you want to connect to a service in another container, you need to use the ip address of that container, or a hostname that resolves to the ip address of that container.

If you are running your containers in a [user-defined network](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/#/user-defined-networks), then Docker maintains a DNS server that will map container names to addresses.  That is, if I first create a network:

```
docker network create myapp_net
```

And then start a rabbitmq container in that network:

```
docker run -d --network myapp_net --hostname rabbitmqhost \
   --name rabbitmq -p 15672:15672 -p 5672:5672 rabbitmq:3-management
```

Then *other* containers started in that network will be able to use the hostname `rabbitmq` to connect to that container.

For containers running in the default network (no `--network` parameter on the command line), you can use the `--link` option to achieve a similar, though less flexible, effect, as documented [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/dockerlinks/).

Comment: Thank you. I ended up using --link to connect each service container to rabbit, even though I appreciate the above is the new standard way of doing it.

Comment: I just wanted to highlight one advantage of the Docker network solution: when using `--link`, if you stop your rabbitmq container, your app is out of luck: you can't "relink" the container after starting a new rabbitmq container.  On the other hand, using Docker networks, which rely on dns for name resolution, if you start a new container with the same name as the new container, your services will probably be able to recover (presuming that your application code handles disconnections gracefully).

Comment: Ahh, that's a very good point, thank you. If I were to use the network solution, what would be the address and port of rabbit? i.e. The equivalent of `AMQ_PORT_5672_TCP_ADDR` and `AMQ_PORT_5672_TCP_PORT`

Comment: The address would just be the name (`--name ...`) of the container (Docker maintains a DNS server that maps container names to address). There is no equivalent to `AMQ_PORT_5672_TCP_PORT`, but in general this isn't an issue.

Comment: Great, thanks again. The only issue I now have is that I cannot access my Flask app (on 0.0.0.0:5000) anymore when the app's container is connected to that network, any ideas?

Comment: Turns out I just didn't map the ports correctly, one I ran with -p 5000:5000 it all works.

Comment: One important point to make here is that all of your service containers need to be started using `--name`. As I found out, without it, container is created but is not put inside the network even if you specify `--network`, thus failing to connect to rabbitMQ