# Not able to connect to rabbit in localhost from the microservice in docker container

Tags: windows, docker, rabbitmq

I have created  a microservice which is having both consumer and  producer for rabbitmq queue. I could run this microservice without any problem in local machine. But when i try to deploy this is docker container , its not able to connect to rabbitmq which in my host machine .

I tried localhost, host machine ip , --add-host , but nothing works for me.

I could ping the host machine ip from container, but telnet is hanging.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40563469/connecting-to-rabbitmq-docker-container-from-service-in-another-container

Comment: How is docker installed on your windows machine? Are you using boot2docker, kitematic or some other installation method?

Comment: I am using docker tool box. And then i creates a docker-machine which is using boot2docker, and running the image from the machine .  docker run -p 5627:5627 -p 15627:15627 <image name>